# Calling randomValue text file method

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a hangman game that picks a random word from a text file of words and then asks the user to guess each letter of the word. Each letter in the word is displayed with an asterisk and when the user makes a correct guess the actual letter is then displayed. After the word is guessed it will then display the number of times missed and ask the user if they want to guess another word. I made a method to get all the values from the text file and store it in a array and then return the values to use but when I call the method it expects to have argument for StreamReader reader and if I put it in it says it is invalid in the given context. I am not sure how I would call this method to use for the random word

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char[] guessed = new char[26];
        char[] testword = "******".ToCharArray();
        char[] word = RandomLine(StreamReader reader);
        char[] copy = word;
        char guess;

        char playAgain;

        int amountMissed = 0, index = 0;
        Console.WriteLine(testword);
        do
        {
            while (testword != word)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I have picked a random word on animals");
                Console.WriteLine("Your task is to guess the correct word");

                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write("Please enter a letter to guess: ");
                    guess = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    bool right = false;
                    for (int j = 0; j < copy.Length; j++)
                    {
                        if (copy[j] == guess)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Your guess is correct.");
                            testword[j] = guess;
                            guessed[index] = guess;
                            index++;
                            right = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (right != true)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Your guess is incorrect.");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        right = false;
                        amountMissed++;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(testword);

                }
                Console.WriteLine($"The word is {word}. You missed {amountMissed} times.");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to gues another word? Enter y or n: ");
            playAgain = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        } while (playAgain == 'y' || playAgain == 'Y');

        Console.WriteLine("Good-Bye and thanks for playing my  Hangman game.");


    }

    public string RandomLine(StreamReader reader)
    {
        // store text file in a array and return a random value
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Intel\\Advanced1.csv"); 
        Random rand = new Random();

        return lines[rand.Next(lines.Length)];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the exact error that was raised to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the Stream reader parameter to RandomLines at all.
It's never used, instead you use File.ReadAllLines to read the file.
If you just get rid of the StreamReader, whatever issues you are having should go away and your code should still function as is.
e.g.:

```
public string RandomLine()
{
    // store text file in a array and return a random value
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Intel\\Advanced1.csv"); 
    Random rand = new Random();

    return lines[rand.Next(lines.Length)];
}
```

And your call to the method should look like this:

```
char[] word = RandomLine();
```